# Different ways to express the idea of something being "concrete" (see provided English example) in adjective form using Japanese?

Tags: phrases, adjectives, definitions, nouns

In English, the noun "concrete" can be used as an adjective to describe other nouns. This usage implies something like "physical", "tangible", "legitimate", or perhaps "consistent". Are there examples of this in Japanese? Beyond just the exact expression: what are words I can use to express the idea that something is "concrete"? Are there words that convey something being more physical, tangible, legitimate, or consistent?

Comment: I think you are looking for 具体的

Answer (score 3):

This English adjective has several meanings. The correct Japanese translation depends on the intended meaning:

1. *concrete* (as opposed to *wooden*, *metallic*, etc.): コンクリートの

   > コンクリートの壁
   > concrete walls
2. *concrete* (as opposed to *abstract*, *vague*): 具体的な

   > 具体的な提案
   > a concrete proposal
3. *concrete* (as opposed to *intangible*, *imaginary*): 形がある・有形の・実体がある

   > 石のような形がある物体
   > concrete objects like stones
4. *concrete* (in programming contexts): 具象

   > インターフェースとそれを実装する具象クラス
   > an interface and a concrete class that implements it

If you want to say something like "consistent and legitimate (opinion/explanation)", しっかりした意見/説明 can be used, too.